# How to replace white markers with custom logo on Google Maps KML file?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, kml, mymaps

We are using the Google JavaScript API to display Google My Maps via a KML file.
The markers on the map are showing white markers and not the custom logo's we have got on My Maps. Does KML not support custom logos for the markers?

[image]

```
<style type="text/css">

html,
body,
#map_canvas {
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px
}

</style>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js? 
key=Your_API_kEY" type="text/javascript"> 
</script>

<script>

var geocoder;
var map;

function initialize() {
var map = new google.maps.Map(
document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});
var layer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
suppressInfoWindows: false,
url: "http://www.linktodata/data.kml",
map: map
})

}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);

</script>
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].  I don't see your issue: [fiddle with KmlLayer from MyMaps with custom icons](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/jar079dL/)

Comment: I found the problem. The URL was linking to the actual .kml file. I think a .kml has limited support for custom icons. You have to link to the MyMaps link if I am not mistaken.

Comment: Both KML and KMZ have support for custom icons, might be the export for MyMaps doesn't (I believe it does say something in the share dialog about that)

Answer (score 0):

The URL: http://www.linktodata/data.kml is wrong. It needs to go to the link within the .kml file.